# dropdown-item href not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 navbar that works well except for one link. The link to the "trainee-portal.php" does nothing on click. Here is the code.

```
    <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="padding: 10px 15px;">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="trainees">Trainees</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="authorRegistration" href="<?php echo site_path(); ?>author-registration.php" class="pseudologin dropdown-item">Become an author</a></li>
        <li><a id="editUserRegistration" href="<?php echo site_path(); ?>user-registration.php" class="pseudologin dropdown-item">Edit my profile</a></li>
        <li><a id="learnerProgress" href="#" class="pseudologin dropdown-item">Resume my cases</a></li>
        <li><a id="learnerPortal" href="<?php echo site_path(); ?>trainee-portal.php" class="pseudologin dropdown-item">Trainee Portal</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
```

The href is correct because it works on all the other links in the unordered list and because I can right-click the item and open "trainee-portal.php" in another tab. I have tried removing the classes and even changed the class dropdown-item to nav-link. It looks different but nothing happens on click. I changed the position in the list. Nothing. I removed the php code in the href to make the link relative. Nothing. I retyped the link with another id. Nothing. BTW pseudologin is simply to open the login form if the user has not signed in. It works but I also tried removing it. Nothing. Am I missing something obvious?
While I am waiting for your input I will use javascript to navigate but that defeats the purpose of href.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does it open if you put the "Resume my cases" link at the very bottom of your list? If so, I would go into the Inspect > Network section of my browser and see if there's something on my paging blocking it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Harley. It makes no difference. I thought the href="#" may somehow interfere with the later href = "a real link path" but it made no difference. Odd?